MongoDB/Mongoose Cursor-Based Pagination: Total Count Incorrect with Search Filter
I'm implementing cursor-based pagination in my NestJS application using MongoDB/Mongoose, but I'm encountering issues with the total count when search filters are applied.
Problem:

When I fetch records with a limit of 10, I get the correct number of items (10)
However, the totalCount in the response shows 10 as well, which is incorrect as there are more matching documents in the database
This affects my frontend pagination calculation

Current Code:
async getRoles(
  paginationDto: CursorPaginationDto,
  sortDto: SortDto,
  searchDto: SearchDto,
): Promise<{
  roles: RoleDocument[];
  pagination: PaginationParams;
}> {
  const { limit = 10, startCursor = '' } = paginationDto;
  let query = this.roleModel.find();
  
  // Apply sorting
  if (sortDto.field) {
    query = query.sort({ [sortDto.field]: sortDto.desc ? -1 : 1 });
  }
  
  // Apply search filter
  if (searchDto.search) {
    const searchTerm = new RegExp(searchDto.search, 'i');
    query = query.or([
      { role: { $regex: searchTerm } },
      { client: { $regex: searchTerm } },
      { endClient: { $regex: searchTerm } },
    ]);
  }
  
  if (startCursor) {
    const decodedCursor = Buffer.from(startCursor, 'base64').toString('ascii');
    query = query.find({ _id: { $gt: decodedCursor } });
  } else {
    query = query.limit(limit);
  }
  
  const countQuery = searchDto.search
    ? query.clone().countDocuments()
    : this.roleModel.countDocuments();
    
  const [roles, total] = await Promise.all([
    query.limit(limit + 1).exec(),
    countQuery,
  ]);
  
  const hasNextPage = roles.length > limit;
  if (hasNextPage) {
    roles.pop();
  }
  
  const startCursorNew = roles.length > 0
    ? Buffer.from(roles[0]._id.toString()).toString('base64')
    : null;
  const endCursor = roles.length > 0
    ? Buffer.from(roles[roles.length - 1]._id.toString()).toString('base64')
    : null;
    
  return {
    roles,
    pagination: {
      totalCount: total,
      hasNextPage,
      hasPreviousPage: !!startCursor,
      startCursor: startCursorNew,
      endCursor,
    },
  };
}

Expected Behavior:
If I have 100 documents in the database and I fetch with limit=10:
Should return 10 items
totalCount should be 100 (or the total number of documents matching the search criteria if search is applied)
hasNextPage should be true
Current Behavior:
Returns 10 items correctly
totalCount is also 10 (incorrect)
Affects pagination calculation in frontend
It sends all the records from the db initially and only leaves the last one to next page,
so this is how i get the data, if there are n records then i get all the n records for the first page, even though the limit is set. and the last record is again fetched for the second page
hence,
first page -> n records,
second page -> last record
that is it
Environment:
NestJS
MongoDB
Mongoose as ORM
Cursor-based pagination implementation
What I've Tried: Initially, I wasn't getting items according to the limit, so I added the else statement I tried moving the count query to different places in the code The items are now correctly limited, but the total count is wrong I tried using query.clone() for the count query when search is applied I have tried placing the code for total count in different locations, sometimes it fetches me every item from the db except the last one. Though, it correctly returns the pagination params correctly in response, its mostly a issue with how i am calculating totalCounts and setting the limit on the records.
Where i think the problem lies
I think the problem lies in how i am trying to count the items after the search has been applied, and i feel that this is the right way to do, may be we can work around here and get it going.

You should need another query to get all the matching document without limit for totalCount.

You can use $facet in a MongoDB aggregation pipeline to process the current page and metadata in one-shot.
As you did not provide any sample data and sample query, below example assume:

sorting on _id field
_id field is used as cursor

The process:

$match with your criteria
$facet to break into 2 parts: metadata and page

metadata: we compute the totalCount and maxCursor here. maxCursor contains the max cursor/_id that a matched record can be
page: get the current page data

$match to be larger than currentCursor
$sort by your sorting
$limit by pageSize




update cursor values by setting next & current cursors and compute hasNextPage by comparing currentCursor with maxCursor

db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      // your criteria here
      "key1": "a"
    }
  },
  {
    "$facet": {
      "metadata": [
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            //total count
            "count": {
              "$sum": 1
            },
            // the min cursor that still contains queried elements
            "minCursor": {
              "$min": "$_id"
            },
            // the max cursor that still contains queried elements
            "maxCursor": {
              "$max": "$_id"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$unset": "_id"
        }
      ],
      "page": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "_id": {
              // your current cursor here; assume we are getting the first page
              "$gt": -1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$sort": {
            // your sort here
            "_id": 1
          }
        },
        {
          // your pageSize here
          "$limit": 10
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$metadata"
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "metadata": {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          "$metadata",
          {
            // your current cursor value
            "previousCursor": -1,
            // your next cursor value=max value in the page
            "currentCursor": {
              "$max": "$page._id"
            },
            // When currentCursor has passed minCursor, we set hasPrevPage to be true
            "hasPrevPage": {
              "$or": [
                {
                  "$eq": [
                    [],
                    "$page"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "$gt": [
                    {
                      "$min": "$page._id"
                    },
                    "$metadata.minCursor"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            // When currentCursor has yet to reach maxCursor, we set hasNextPage to be true
            "hasNextPage": {
              "$and": [
                {
                  $ne: [
                    [],
                    "$page"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "$lt": [
                    {
                      "$max": "$page._id"
                    },
                    "$metadata.maxCursor"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])

Mongo Playground

This is nice, can i also add hasPreviousPage, as i also need to move backward in the pagination. i can just compute something as
hasPreviousPage: {
"gt": [
currentcursor,
mincursor
]
}

@mo-shahab updated the answer. The concept is similar to hasNextPage, by comparing the currentCursor to minCursor / maxCursor

this is great, i will try to use this
